# Pivot table based on same column values

Tags: oracle

I am trying to pivot some data
Here is my original table

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim |
| 1 | Joe |
| 2 | Jak |
| 2 | Den |
| 2 | Din |
| 3 | Kos |
| 3 | Kos2 |
| 3 | Sah |

What I am trying to have (Maximum 4 name columns):

| ID | NAME1 | NAME2 | NAME3 | NAME4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim | Joe |  |  |
| 2 | Jak | Den | Din |  |
| 3 | Kos | Kos2 | Sah |  |

I have found some examples and tried to follow them but with no success

Comment: Is there a column which provides the ordering of names which you perceive to exist?

Comment: No @TimBiegeleisen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to give each name a unique number per id and then pivot on that number:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY name) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(name)
  FOR rn IN (1 AS name1, 2 AS name2, 3 AS name3, 4 AS name4)
)
```

or, using conditional aggregation to pivot:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN name END) AS name1,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 2 THEN name END) AS name2,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 3 THEN name END) AS name3,
       MAX(CASE rn WHEN 4 THEN name END) AS name4
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY name) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
GROUP BY id
```

*Note: If you want to display the names in the order that they are read from the table then you can use `PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ROWNUM`. If you have an alternative method of ordering the names then specify that in the `ORDER BY`.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, NAME) AS
SELECT 1, 'Jim' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Joe' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Jak' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Den' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Din' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Kos' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Kos2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Sah' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| ID | NAME1 | NAME2 | NAME3 | NAME4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jim | Joe | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | Den | Din | Jak | *null* |
| 3 | Kos | Kos2 | Sah | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EH7AXOXs)

Comment: Thanks @MT0. Your first suggestion worked